# making android gotosleep work!

Tags: android, sleep, sample

Just like the "Invisible Lock Widget" and "Screen Off and Lock" I want to make my android app gotosleep.

Does anyone have any sample code or guide for doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that I can to this by using the same function in DeviceAdminSample.java

It is actually not using goToSleep function, it can be done in different way.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.html